# Delete query not working fine with timestamp

Tags: sql-server-2005

I have an table1 like this

```
 ID   InsertDateTime  
 1      2012-03-28 07:21:09.717
 2      2012-03-28 07:22:09.717
 3      2012-03-28 01:21:09.717
 4      2012-03-28 03:21:09.717
 5      2012-03-28 09:21:09.717
 6      2012-03-23 07:21:09.717
 7      2012-03-24 07:22:09.717
```

Now I need to delete data for particular day only, I am trying like this but it is not working:

```
delete from table1 where  InsertDateTime  ='2012-03-28'
```

Answer (score 3):

```
delete from table1
where InsertDateTime >= '20120328' and
      InsertDateTime < '20120329'
```

Answer (score 0):

As your Time entered in the database is in  '2012-03-28 07:21:09.717' format ,
when u write a query like this

```
delete from table1 where  InsertDateTime  ='2012-03-28'
```

It will assume as '2012-03-28 00:00:00.000'.but as u dont have that timestamp, it is not working.

So try to give

```
delete from table1 where InsertDateTime >= '2012-03-28' and InsertDateTime < '2012-03-29'
```